# C++ example to disable a network adapter in Windows server 2008 r2

Tags: c++, winapi, network-programming, windows-server-2008-r2

On Windows Server 2008 R2 we have multiple network adapters.  We have a legacy program that has to bind with a particular network adapter.   It does not always select the correct one.  I need to disable the incorrect network adapters, then start the program and then enable the network adapters again.
I am having trouble disabling the adapters.  Could someone provide a C++ example?
The compiler is Embarcadero C++ XE2.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to try and fix the program instead? If you can show us (by editing the question and add the code, or (and the preferred way) add a new question for that) how it binds to an address, maybe we can help you with that?

Comment: Surely just giving the correct address to the `bind()` call will fix the problem?

Comment: Lost the source code for the program.  It is scheduled to be rewritten next year.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not necessary to use c++. 
Batch file can do it.

The file is as below:

To disable the interface run:

```
netsh interface set interface “Local Area Connection” DISABLED
```

To enable the interface run:

```
netsh interface set interface “Local Area Connection” ENABLED
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Pablo, this is the c++ command:

```
HINSTANCE retVal = ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "cmd", "/c netsh interface set interface \"Local Area Connection\" ENABLED", NULL, SW_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use c++ to run a script
Like a ps1 script

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).