# SetupDiSetClassInstallParamsW Windows API failing

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Below is the code which is calling Windows SetupDiSetClassInstallParamsW
method --

```
 bool
Util::SvmDisableNic(HDEVINFO devInfoSet, SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfo)
{
   SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS params = {0};
   SP_DEVINSTALL_PARAMS_W installParams = {0};

   //
   // Disable device
   //
   params.ClassInstallHeader.cbSize = sizeof(SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER);
   params.ClassInstallHeader.InstallFunction = DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE;
   params.StateChange = DICS_DISABLE;
   params.Scope = DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL;
   params.HwProfile = 0;

   if (!SetupDiSetClassInstallParamsW(devInfoSet, &deviceInfo,
                                      &(params.ClassInstallHeader),
                                      sizeof params)) {
      DWORD err = GetLastError();
      SYSMSG_FUNC(
         Debug, _T("Failed setting device params to disable: Err: 0x%X"), err);
      return false;
   }
```

This code is running successfully, however, in a couple of VMs, the 
SetupDiSetClassInstallParamsW is failing, and GetLastError is returning an error code of  0xD. From microsoft doc, looks like this corresponds to ERROR_INVALID_DATA. The VMs in which this code is running successfully and in those in which it is failing, are identical in terms of hardware/software configuration. Any idea how we can debug why this windows API is failing?

Comment: Relevant duplicates [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860673/programmatically-disable-enable-network-interface), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855567/c-example-to-disable-a-network-adapter-in-windows-server-2008-r2), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331449/disabling-enabling-network-interfaces-via-winapi).

Comment: What interface do you use `SetupDiSetClassInstallParamsW` to disable? What is the operating system in the VM?

Comment: I am trying to disable NIC card using the above API. The OS is Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise build 17134. It is 64 bit OS (both the working and failed ones)

Comment: Just thinking, will using FormatMessage API give some more clue for the cause of failure other than just calling GetLastError?

Comment: What's the value of deviceInfo parameter when you got this error? And  is all the VMs are on the same PC?